# Generic T in method parameter in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, methods, generic-list

I like to do something like this:

```
public static List<string> ItemsOfEnum(T typeT)
{
    List<string> items = new List<string>();
    foreach (typeT tItem in Enum.GetValues(typeof(typeT)))
       items.Add(tItem);
    return items;
}
```

How to get the "T" in the parameter-list without changing the return type (List)?

Comment: Erm, not sure what you are asking. Could you clarify your question?

Comment: You can use `Enum.GetNames` to get a `string[]`. Not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: There are 3 answers posted but I still have no clue what the question was :)

Comment: I wanted to know, where to place the 'T'. I thought, I had to insert it behind the 'string'. (`List<string, T>`) But this had changed the output result or better said ended up wih an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems to easy... but maybe that's what you were looking for?

```
public static List<string> ItemsOfEnum<typeT>()
        where typeT: struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible {
    List<string> items = new List<string>();
    foreach (typeT tItem in Enum.GetValues(typeof(typeT)))
       items.Add(tItem.ToString());
    return items;
}
```

Note that C# doesn't allow to constrain to enums, so those constraints are more or less the closes you can get.

Comment: Thank you @Lucero. That was the point. I tried something like 'code'List<string, typeT>'code' but this had changed the return type. Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome. If you're only after the enum names though you may want to directly use `Enum.GetNames` (just as Oded suggested).

Answer (score 1):

I think you mixed up the Syntax. I guess you want something like this:

```
public static List<string> ItemsOfEnum<T>(T inputList) {...}
```

In your for each statement you need to exchange typeT with T. Maybe for your internal list you need to call the toString function to get a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static List<string> itemsofenum<typet>()
  { ... }
```

Comment: It will, if typet is a type variable so that he can call typeof on it.

Comment: C# is case sensitive. `Public` and `list<string>` are incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for this valuable comment.

Comment: My point is that if you are going to post code samples, at least make them something that can be used directly. Made the changes for you.

Comment: I know that, i should not use ipad to post here :)

Comment: That would explain it... An environment hostile to C# ;)